# List of allowed mac addresses for port security

Tags: cisco, switch, mac-address, port-security

Want to be sure I'm approaching this correctly.

I want to have a list of allowed MACs that can access any switch company wide (these devices can plug into any switch and be allowed access).

To do this I would have a list of the MAC addresses and then programmatically apply this list to each switch's switch ports I have enabled for port security.

Is there a different or more efficient way of going about this?

Comment: Port security can't have the same MAC address on multiple ports of the same switch, since that defeats the port security. MAC addresses are easily spoofed, so what you are proposing is a lot of work for very little return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go for IEEE 802.1x Port-Based Authentication. Port security was not really designed for that.

HTH
Adam

Comment: I wanted to avoid having to go through setting up radius and authentication if possible. Is there a limit to the amount of allowed macs you can assign a switchport?

Comment: Switch(config-if)#switchport port-security maximum ?
  <1-132>  Maximum addresses                                 The range is from 1  to 132 at least on a 2960.

Comment: If you set it  to  2 you will get the following message when configuring the third MAC  **Total secure mac-addresses on interface FastEthernet0/1 has reached maximum limit.**